# Modx revolution access resource

Tags: modx-revolution

Is it possible for a snippet to access the content of a specific resource? I want users to be able to edit content of the resource and then have it used in various parts of the site. It wont need any dynamic data putting into it, as the user will be modifying this as and when required.

I am going to use it the way you would use a chunk, but I don't want the user to edit any chunks.
Thanks
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - that's how snippets like Wayfinder and getResources work, and there is already a snippet that does exactly what you want: getResourceField [Link to AddOn RTFM](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/getResourceField)